# Weird behaviour of ALSA with both paplay and vlc

Tags: audio, debian, alsa, pulseaudio, vlc

Jack sound works well on my headless Debian Raspberry with `omxplayer` and pretty much any file.

However, alsa-based programs output a buggish sound and regularly fail. Here is a (maybe) interesting output:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

This command produces random results:

```
$ paplay test_file.ogg  # will work fine
$ paplay test_file.ogg  # will wait forever and I hear nothing
^C
$ paplay test_file.ogg  # will output buggish sound
```

(.. soon after I run it, `aplay -l` outputs `Subdevices: 7/8`, it is then shortly restored to `8/8`.)

Considering the `vlc-nox` package. I get (very) buggish sound and the beginning of the file is not even played when I run:

```
$ cvlc long_file.mp3
VLC media player 2.2.4 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.3-37-g888b7e89)
[016ab088] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[0156b8f8] core libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[016ab088] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[016ab088] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[0156b8f8] core libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[016ab088] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[015f68b0] alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
[015f68b0] alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
[015f68b0] alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
[015f68b0] alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
[015f68b0] alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
[015f68b0] alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
[015f68b0] alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
[015f68b0] alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
[015f68b0] alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
[015f68b0] alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
[015f68b0] alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
[015f68b0] alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
[015f68b0] alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
[015f68b0] alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
[015f68b0] alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
[015f68b0] alsa audio output error: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
```

How come I get such bad results when `omxplayer` still works fine? How come `cvlc` seems looking for a D-Bus interface when I got it from the `vlc-nox` package?

Problems persist after reboot and reinstallation of all `pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-zeroconf alsa-utils avahi-daemon vlc-nox` packages.

Comment: I think some audio apps have separate backends for alsa and pulseaudio; the former is for use sans pulseaudio.  You may want to look into that.

Comment: @goldilocks I'm not sure to understand. Do you you mean I should try to configure `cvlc` and `paplay` to work with `alsa` and without `pulseaudio`?

Comment: No; if you are using pulseaudio I'm suggesting the opposite of that. Check and see if they are configured to use alsa directly when it should be via pulseaudio.  Also, if you don't need pulseaudio (I think jack might?) then don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I was just running into this issue today.  I had jackd, jackd2, and pulseaudio installed, and I couldn't get any decent playback of my sound files.  I wasn't actually using any of those packages for playback, I was just attempting to use Alsa.

After running: `sudo apt-get remove jackd jackd2 pulseaudio` I'm actually able to playback my files using certain methods.

I'm not sure if one of those is the particular culprit or if you need to remove all 3, but I think if you don't need them, removing them will fix your issue.

I'm now able to playback mp3's just fine with vlc (no more "cannot estimate delay"!) and alsaplayer, however for some reason aplay still gives me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue and the problem was that the audio file was too much for the CPU to handle.  Once it gets to 100% CPU weird things happen with Pulseaudio, from the audio getting choppy to devices disappearing and reappearing.

You can run `top` to see if this is your problem, and make sure you are under 90% CPU use while playing audio.

If you are hitting 100% CPU use, there are a few things you can try, such as lowering the sampling rate or using a less CPU-intensive resampling algorithm (the one used by default in Pulseaudio favours quality over performance).  If you have Pulseaudio installed, it will usually be configured to route ALSA audio via Pulseaudio, so even if you think you're only using ALSA, you may want to check this.

Ultimately I found the Pi 1 was just not powerful enough to handle more than 2-3 Pulseaudio streams, so I replaced it with a Pi 3 and all the choppy audio went away.